# Why doesn't the redirection working for the Next.Js whenever I copy the URL and paste it?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, firebase-hosting

So I am creating a web application. Which is using React and Next.JS as backend with Firebase as the database. The data fetching and stuff is working. The issue here is I have a button on my UserDashboard that goes to a specific Profile Viewing page. For example, localhost:3000/profiles/ is the URL when I click the button. Now this works in the local test. Whenever I copy that URL with different UniqueProfileIDs it redirects and goes to the correct profile page. But when I host it through firebase- Everytime I copy the URL to that related way "www.exampleapp.web.app/profiles/ it instead redirects to the UserDashboard instead. I don't know what is wrong here? It's like when you type in the URL 'instagram.com/profileName' and it directly takes to the profile even if you have an account or not. I need this to work here too-

I have already created a dynamic routing under public directory and under public another directory called 'profiles'

**Below is part my code for UserDashboard.js** where how the button works. I tried not giving Firebase Auth hooks for the page too but did not work. I want this page to be accessible by anyone to view the profile.

```
 </Link>
      <Link href={`/profiles/${currentUser.uid}`}>
        View My Profile
      </Link>
```

**Below here my code for `[uniqueId].js` under the profiles directory.**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { getDoc, doc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db } from '@/firebase'; // Adjust import path

export default function UserProfilePage({ uid }) {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const userRef = doc(db, 'users', uid);
    getDoc(userRef)
      .then((docSnapshot) => {
        if (docSnapshot.exists()) {
          setUserData(docSnapshot.data().Info);
        } else {
          setError('User data not found');
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setError('Error fetching user data');
        console.error('Error fetching user data:', error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, [uid]);

  if (loading) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }

  if (error) {
    return <p>Error: {error}</p>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {userData ? (
        <div>
          <h2>User Profile</h2>
          <p>First Name: {userData['First Name']}</p>
          <p>Last Name: {userData['Last Name']}</p>
          <p>Contact Number: {userData['Contact Number']}</p>
          {/* Display other user details */}
        </div>
      ) : (
        <p>User data not available</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps({ params }) {
  return {
    props: {
      uid: params.uid,
    },
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've configured Firebase Hosting to rewrite all incoming URLs back to the root of the web site. This is common for single-page applications, which is why it is one of the questions that the Firebase CLI asks you when you first configure hosting, but it sounds like it is not what you want here.

Read the documentation on [configuring rewrites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites), then open the `firebase.json` configuration file of your web site, find the `rewrites` section in there, and remove the rewrite that looks like this (from the linked documentation):

```
"hosting": {
  // ...

  // Serves index.html for requests to files or directories that do not exist
  "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  } ]
}
```